# Determining the importance of Helmut Kohl's role in the German Reunification

Tags: germany, german-unification

A week ago, former German chancellor [Helmut Kohl died](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmut_Kohl). Now some of the orbituaries in common newspapers pick up again the debate on what Kohl's role was in the [German Reunification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_reunification), during which he was chancellor of West Germany. Some frame him as "The Chancellor Of Reunification", implying an important role in the process, others say "he was just there at the right place and the right time" and that the Reunification basically fell into his lap.

I would love to do a little research on this, but I have basically no idea how to properly conduct history research. German and english wikipedia articles on the Reunification subject talk about the Allied Forces leader's positions, but now about how they were eventually changed. Do I need to consult history books (and trust their authors to a degree not to be biased), are there proceedings from the [Two Plus Four Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Final_Settlement_with_Respect_to_Germany) negotiations I can read? What else would you suggest?

Comment: I would find out the two most respected authors on both sides (kohl-boosters and kohl-dismissers) and read their books or articles. If they cite evidence you find persuasive, see if it's possible to look at that evidence yourself. The answer is a matter of opinion, obviously.

Comment: One thing occurs: Kohl cultivated a close relationship with Gorbachev. Gorbachev declined to use the red army to crush the East German protestors, as the Soviets had done many times before